# how to make a button download a python file in html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I've tried several ways such as:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="window.open('client.py')"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
```

or

```
<a href="/D:/Website/client.py" download>
  python file
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" data-href='https://i.imgur.com/Mc12OXx.png' download="Image.jpg" onclick='forceDownload(this)'>Download Image</a>
```

js part:

```
function forceDownload(link){
    var url = link.getAttribute("data-href");
    var fileName = link.getAttribute("download");
    link.innerText = "Working...";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = imageUrl;
        tag.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        tag.click();
        document.body.removeChild(tag);
        link.innerText="Download Image";
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

but all of them seem to open the python file in a new window. and that new window/tab, just displays the file's code on the screen...
I however, want the file to be downloaded on the computer, not opened in another window!
*The last code that I referenced didn't work at all, I'm not sure why, also it's a bad example because I was trying to use that code to download a picture and not a python file, but you get the idea, in addition, I struggle understanding the code, since it uses js and js is a language I have very little knowledge in.
could anyone help?

Comment: In a lot of ways, this is up to the browser. Your server can also try to send more information about the file including using the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you were saying after the first sentence

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the button

```
<form method="get" action="client.py">
   <button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, that code still opens the python file in a new tab and just displays it's code on the screen...